# How Can I Use only the Day Month Year with UIDatePickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I'd like to change the format of my UIDatePicker so it can look like "Year-Month-Day" without the hours. Doesn't have to be in that exact order my main goal is to not have the hours minutes and AM/PM.

Is there any way to do that ???

Comment: just set the picker mode to date and get the year, month and day components from the selected date

Answer (score 0):

You can set mode of `UIDatePickerView` to Date , Time , DateTime Or Count Down Timer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set Mode to "Date" on story builder from available modes: Date, Time, Date and Time and Cound down.

Example (marked red):
[image]

Or programatically:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
```

Comment: Ah! is there anyway to do this programmatically?

Comment: @JulianCearley Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) especially [UIDatePickerMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickermode)